# How can I get a 32-bit output with Python on a 64-bit system?

Tags: python, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I have a 64-bit system with both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Python installed.
I code using Visual Studio and output it using the auto-py-to-exe tool.
How can I get a 32-bit output from my code?
Is there a way to change the Python version (32 and 64 bit) used in Visual Studio Code?

I tried to change the language of the Visual Studio Code to 32-bit Python mode, but the output failed.
By doing this, I expected the exe output I got to be 32-bit, but it was still 64-bit.

Comment: make sure that you run auto-py-to-exe from the 32 bit version.

Comment: [Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio) or [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code)? They are completely different. I presume it can't be both in this particular case. Blame Microsoft Marketing for the confusion.

Comment: OK, the OP has probably [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than a week ago"*